# Jersey with Jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jersey

Here is my web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans-web.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.ImplicitViewables</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/(images|css)/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

For request `GET http://localhost:8082/so/`

If I wont specify root context as /v1/* i am getting bellow exception

```
2 > GET http://localhost:8082/so/
2 > Host: localhost:8082
2 > User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10
```

and again internally redirecting to

```
3 > GET http://localhost:8082/so/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
3 > Host: localhost:8082
3 > User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10
```

And fails INFO:

```
3 * Server out-bound response
3 < 404

INFO: 2 * Server out-bound response
2 < 200
2 < Content-Type: text/html
```

If I put root context to /v1/* works fine..

Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer here [Spring, Jersey and Viewable JSP Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559893/spring-jersey-and-viewable-jsp-integration). You have to use the SpringServlet as a filter instead of a servlet in the web.xml.